# Replace several strings with other string in several files

Tags: vim

I have several text files. All these text files need to undergo a set to editing which can be done in `vim`. I want to automate this. `vim` has several commands for replacement. Suppose the text files need to undergo the following replacements:

1. replace boy by Boy: `%s/boy/Boy/g`
2. replace girl by Girl: `%s/girl/Girl/g`
3. delete empty lines: `g/^$/d`

This is just a simple example, Is there a way to write all these rules and then automate this on several files?

Comment: I changed your question from vi to vim since I assumed that's what you were using. Please confirm this.

Comment: @braiam - what about using vim?

Comment: @slm I presume the tag is enough... the original title didn't reflect what was the task at hand and was actually misleading.

Answer (score 15):

Yes there is a way to automate this. And it starts with selecting the right tool, for the job.
In this case you should be using e.g `sed` and not try to bend `vi` which was designed for interactive use (and not for automation).

The replacement syntax for `sed` is largely the same as the one for `vi`.

```
 sed -i.backup 's/boy/Boy/g' file-name-1 file-name-2 ...
```

Comment: Apparently there's an echo in here, 4 others felt to say exactly what you did 8-)

Comment: `sed` is a **stream** editor, `vi` is a _visual_ text **file** editor, built on top of `ex`/`ed` (and the `s` command is an `ex` command in `vi`). Most `sed` implementations don't have a `-i`. `ex` and `ed` are standard Unix commands. So yes, it can be done with some sed implementations, but that is not to say it is the _right_ tool.

Comment: I didn't write `sed` is "the right tool". There are multiple tools, hence the "e.g.". As far as I remember `ed` didn't operate on multiple files and you would have to provide read and write operations on its stdin. However the last time I can remember I used `ed` was because `vi` was not available on a PDP-11 in the mid 80s, so I might be out of date with its capabilities

Answer (score 13):

Vim scripts (gvim,vim) can be elegant and are very easy to adapt

```
vi -s edit.vim  test.txt
```

where  edit.vim contains (the :wq is optional)

```
:%s/boy/Boy/g
:%s/girl/Girl/g
:g/^$/d
:wq
```

where test.txt contains

```
boys & girls

boys & girls
boy & girl

boys & girls
```

here's a generic vim script to clean up a "mucky" text file

```
:" clean.vim
:" clean up a text file
:" delete DOS returns (actually superfluous because of non-ASCII
deletion)
:%s/\r//eg
:" delete any non-ASCII including invisibles
:%s/[\x00-\x1f\x80-\xff]/ /eg
:" compress multiple spaces
:%s/\s\s\+/ /eg
:" delete end of line spaces
:%s/\s\+$//e
:" compress multiple blank lines
:v/./,/./-j
:" sort eliminating duplicate lines
:%sort -u
```

remember you can also source the script from within vim

```
:source clean.vim
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `sed` ?

With sed you could easily loop over the files in the directory:

```
for f in *.txt
do
sed 's/boy/Boy/g;s/girl/Girl/g;/^\s*$/d' $f > tmp
mv tmp $f
done
```

Above example would change boy->Boy, girl->Girl and delete empty the lines.

Comment: You do not need to do the for loop, give sed a list of files directly as in Anthon's answer below or the glob, *.txt directly. Also the `mv` is unnecessary. Use `sed`'s `-i.ext` switch to create a backup.

Comment: I didn't know that trick I will try to remember it the next time. Thanks for the tip and explanation @slm

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE:** Using `sed` is the appropriate way to do this, as shown by [@Anthon's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156017/7453)!

---

Just to show you how you could do this in `vim`. You can use the `argdo` command within `vim`. From the `:help argdo` in `vim`:

```
:argdo[!] {cmd}         Execute {cmd} for each file in the argument list.
```

Example:

```
    :args *.c
    :argdo set ff=unix | update
```

This sets the 'fileformat' option to "unix" and writes the file if it is now
changed.  This is done for all `*.c` files.

Example:

```
    :args *.[ch]
    :argdo %s/\<my_foo\>/My_Foo/ge | update
```

This changes the word "my_foo" to "My_Foo" in all `*.c` and `*.h` files.  The "e" flag is used for the `:substitute` command to avoid an error for files where
"my_foo" isn't used.  `:update` writes the file only if changes were made.

The command `:args <pattern>` tells `:argdo` which files you want to run the following `{cmd}` against. Once defined you run `:argdo {cmd} | update` where `{cmd}` can be your `s/boy/Boy/g` substitution.

#### Are the files all opened during this operation?

It would appear so. I did the following test to confirm this.

```
$ for i in {1..3};do echo "dog" > file${i}.txt;done

$ head file*.txt
==> file1.txt <==
dog

==> file2.txt <==
dog

==> file3.txt <==
dog
```

Now go into `vim` and do the following commands:

```
:args file*.txt
```

You can confirm that they've all been opened:

```
:ls
  2 %a   "file1.txt"                    line 1
  3      "file2.txt"                    line 0
  4      "file3.txt"                    line 0
```

Do `:argdo ...`:

```
:argdo %s/dog/cat/g | update
"file1.txt" 1L, 4C written
"file2.txt" 1L, 4C written
"file3.txt" 1L, 4C written
```

So keep this in mind if you intend to use this approach. It inefficiently opens every file that matches your pattern to `:args` and applies the command to them in turn.

Answer (score 2):

And an inline `vi` script:

```
$ vi test.txt -c '%s/boy/Boy/g | %s/girl/Girl/g | g/^$/d | wq'
```

Answer (score 0):

I second [@Anthon's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156017/7453). Use `sed`:

```
$ sed -e "s/boy/Boy/g" -e "s/girl/Girl/g" -e '/^\s*$/d' file
```

**NOTE:** (This also deletes lines with only whitespaces)

Add `-i` to `sed` if you want to replace in-place (your files are under version control, right?). For multiple files:

```
$ for $f in $(ls mydir); do
   sed -e "s/boy/Boy/g" -e "s/girl/Girl/g" -e '/^\s*$/d' $f
done
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is the tool for you.  Most of the commands that you will use in `vi` will be available in `sed` and so, there is not much learning curve.  The commands in `vi` that are started with a `:` are based on the underlying editor `ed` and they are also available in `sed`.  You will use those commands without the `:` and they are, by default, applied to the entire file.  For example, for your example, you will do

```
sed -i 's/boy/Boy/g
s/girl/Girl/g
/^$/d' file1 file2 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `vi` is actually `vim` or `gvim`, it can certainly be implemented in vimscript, but it may be complicated to work on multiple files at once.

Better the right tool for the job: `sed`, the stream editor, which used a very similar syntax like `vi`, but is intended to work on files as a stream line by line, without interaction.

With the option `-i`, `sed` can do changes in multiple files. `-i.backup moves an original file`foo.txt`to`foo.txt.backup`, and applies changes in place to`foo.txt`:

```
sed -i.backup -e 's/boy/Boy/g' -e 's/girl/Girl/g' -e '/^$/d' f1.txt f2.txt ...
```

You can run this inside `vi` too with `:!`:

```
:!sed -i.backup -e 's/boy/Boy/g' -e 's/girl/Girl/g' -e '/^$/d' f1.txt f2.txt ...
```

Answer (score 0):

### Alternatives

Unless you really need special Vim capabilities, you're probably better off using *non-interactive tools* like `sed`, `awk`, or Perl / Python / Ruby / *your favorite scripting language here*.

That said, you can use Vim non-interactively:

### Silent Batch Mode

For very simple text processing (i.e. using Vim like an enhanced 'sed' or 'awk', maybe just benefitting from the enhanced regular expressions in a `:substitute` command), use *Ex-mode*.

```
REM Windows
call vim -N -u NONE -n -es -S "commands.ex" "filespec"
```

Note: silent batch mode (`:help -s-ex`) messes up the Windows console, so you may have to do a `cls` to clean up after the Vim run.

```
# Unix
vim -T dumb --noplugin -n -es -S "commands.ex" "filespec"
```

Attention: Vim will hang waiting for input if the `"commands.ex"` file doesn't exist; better check beforehand for its existence! Alternatively, Vim can read the commands from stdin. You can also fill a new buffer with text read from stdin, and read commands from stderr if you use the `-` argument.

### Full Automation

For more advanced processing involving multiple windows, and real automation of Vim (where you might interact with the user or leave Vim running to let the user take over), use:

```
vim -N -u NONE -n -c "set nomore" -S "commands.vim" "filespec"
```

Here's a summary of the used arguments:

```
-T dumb           Avoids errors in case the terminal detection goes wrong.
-N -u NONE        Do not load vimrc and plugins, alternatively:
--noplugin        Do not load plugins.
-n                No swapfile.
-es               Ex mode + silent batch mode -s-ex
                Attention: Must be given in that order!
-S ...            Source script.
-c 'set nomore'   Suppress the more-prompt when the screen is filled
                with messages or output to avoid blocking.
```